# Outer Joining to more than 1 Table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have this join query below , which fethces me the results that I am looking for.

```
select  TA.ColumnB,TB.ColumnB 
    from TableA TA,TableB TB, TableC TC 
    where
        TA.ColumnA=TB.ColumnA(+)
        and TB.ColumnA = TC.ColumnA(+)
        AND TA.ColumnC = 'ABC'
```

Results ==> `3 Rows`

Tables are as below :

[image]
[image]
[image]

The required result :

[image]

I was wondering if there a way to write the same in explicity in JOIN instead of the `(+)` symbol . Since `TableB.ColumnA` is a common denominator in both the where conditions , can I reduce the code somehow or write this differently to reduce no of outer joins?

I have tried 
**Attempt 1**

```
 Select 
               TA.ColumnB,TB.ColumnB 
               from  TableA TA
               LEFT JOIN TableB TB ON (TA.ColumnA = TB.ColumnA)
               LEFT JOIN TableC TC ON (TB.ColumnA = TC.ColumnA)
               AND TA.ColumnC = 'ABC'
```

Result ==> Huge number of rows

**Attempt 2**

```
 Select 
               TA.ColumnB,TB.ColumnB 
               from  TableA TA
               LEFT JOIN TableB TB ON (TA.ColumnA = TB.ColumnA)
               JOIN TableC TC ON (TB.ColumnA = TC.ColumnA)
               AND TA.ColumnC = 'ABC'
```

Result ==> `2 rows`

Comment: Tried that already Mate (Attempt 1) , it doesn't fetch the required number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try

```
Select TA.ColumnB,TB.ColumnB from 
TableC TC 
LEFT JOIN TableB TB ON (TC.ColumnA = TB.ColumnA)
LEFT JOIN TableA TA ON (TB.ColumnA = TA.ColumnA)
```

Comment: This fetches no of rows in result equals `TableC` , my requirement is no of rows in result should be equal to `TableA`

Comment: In this case your Attempt 1 should have been worked.do you have only three rows in tableA? ot would be better if you will show couple of records from tableA,B,C.

Comment: actually the no of rows in the result should be , row count  Table A(after a where condition on TableA) . With Attempt1 I am getting the whole count of TableA

Comment: am I correct to believe that you forget to mention ** AND TA.ColumnC = 'ABC'** condition earlier. If question is solved then we can think it as closed ...

Comment: Yep Mate , I though initially it doesn't ahve any relevance , But later I realized that it does. Anyways , if you update the answer, I will accept yours as you did try to help me with the solution :)

Comment: Its not a problem ... at the end you got the solution is more important for me .

Answer (score 1):

My attempt 1 was very near to the solution. A `where` condition resolved the issue . I was using and instead of where which might have caused the issue

```
Select 
               TA.ColumnB,TB.ColumnB 
               from  TableA TA
               LEFT JOIN TableB TB ON (TA.ColumnA = TB.ColumnA)
               LEFT JOIN TableC TC ON (TB.ColumnA = TC.ColumnA)
               where TA.ColumnC = 'ABC'
```

Comment: Why are you including TableC into the query to begin with? Judging by your example, you are not pulling any columns from it. The only potential effect of such a left join would be duplication of rows.

Comment: @AndriyM Mate I need this table joined so that that I can join TableC with another table later . I haven't provided the whole complex query I'm working on , just the part I had doubts with :)